# Como mover el navegador a la derecha o izquierda con selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Quisiera mover la ventana de mi navegador hacia el lado izquierdo o derecho de la pantalla. Manualmente presionaría [WINDOW] + [flecha derecha] (o [flecha izquierda]) para hacerlo.

Entonces deberia ser algo asi:

```
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.WIN +  Keys.RIGHT) 
o
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.WIN +  Keys.ARROW_RIGHT)
o
d = webdriver.ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.WIN + Keys.ARROW_RIGHT).perform()
```

pero esto da error diciendo "no se encuentra la tecla WIN".
Quisiera saber como simular la tecla windows para mover el navegador hacia la derecha.

edit: tengo entendido que la tecla windows es una combinacion de otras.. pero si la quiero simular con ctrl+escape+flecha_derecha, esto no funciona ni si quiera manualmente.

Comment: hace mucho que no uso selenium y no sé si entendí, ¿por qué no usar? driver.set_window_position(0, 0) donde podrías establecer la ubicación que quieras

Comment: Si actualmente estoy usándolo de esa manera cambiando posición y tamaño.. el problema es que muchas veces conecto una pantalla externa y vuelven a cambiar las características.. por eso mejor me gustaría hacerlo con Windows + flecha derecha por ejemplo.... Entiendo que el problema está en que la tecla de Windows es un conjunto de ctrl + esc.. pero como describí arriba al enviarlas no funciona.. ni manualmente

Comment: Si es solo para uso personal, como selenium no incorpora la tecla "WIN" podrías reemplazar el uso de ésta dentro del sistema asignandole otra, el problema es que tendrás que usar esa combinación para cualquier otra cosa en la cual necesites esa combinación.

Comment: agradezco tu respuesta.. pero no es lo que estoy buscando... me encantaría encontrar el funcionamiento correcto.

Comment: el problema, salvo que haya una versión nueva que lo ya hecho y por supuesto puedo no estar enterado, "WIN" no está dentro de la clase de teclas de selenum, por lo tanto no se puede usar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo puedes posicionar de la siguiente manera:

```
driver.manage().window().setPosition(new Point(100,200));
```

De igual forma, para realizar lo que necesitas te recomiendo utilizar un módulo llamado `pyautogui` que te permitirá mover cualquier elemento de tu sistema. Para instalarlo en windows escribe en la consola `pip install pyautogui`, en caso de que utilices linux, escribe en la terminal `python -m pip install pyautogui`.

Toma como referencia las coordenadas de tu cursor. Para eso te recomiendo utilizar el siguiente código. Que te irá diciendo las coordenadas en tiempo real del cursor sin añadir nada más.

```
from ctypes import windll, Structure, c_long, byref 
import os
class POINT(Structure): 
    _fields_ = [("x", c_long), ("y", c_long)] #Se declara las longitudes referentes del posicionamiento del "alto" y "largo"
def queryMousePosition():
    pt = POINT()
    windll.user32.GetCursorPos(byref(pt))
    return {"x": pt.x, "y": pt.y}
x=1
while (x > 0): #Por último se crea un ciclo while que nos arrojará de manera indefinida en la posición del cursor
    x+=1 
    punto=queryMousePosition() 
    print(punto) 
    os.system('cls') #Para que solo se muestre una sola línea, se borra la línea anterior
```

Ahora que ya sabemos las coordenadas de tu cursor, importamos `pyautogui` y `sys`:

```
import pyautogui
import sys

#La función a prueba de fallas detendrá el programa si mueve rápidamente el mouse lo más arriba y hacia la izquierda que pueda.
pyautogui.FAILSAFE = False #Deshabilitamos la prueba de fallos

#Para mover cualquier cosa del sistema, declaramos `pyautogui.moveTo`(Coordenadas)
pyautogui.moveTo(543, 743) #Voy a tomar como referencia el segundo icono que están en la barra de tareas (donde 543 = `x` y 743 = `y`) 
#Finalmente indicamos en dónde queremos dejar el elemento arrastrado, donde indicamos las coordenadas y el tiempo de duración.
pyautogui.dragRel(928, 741, duration=0.3)
sys.exit() #Cerramos pyautogui
```

Espero que pueda servirte, Saludos!

Comment: Está respuesta es muy completa.. y la tomo como correcta.. por el hecho de que la tecla Windows no es encontrada por selenium y al emularla con otras teclas no cumple la misma función..